Inner CV joint clunks and has play, is the CV axle bad?
Vehicle: 2006 VW with 180k miles. 2.0 TDI w/ DSG transmission if relevant.
After a recent 1000mi drive including some bumpy roads, I've noticed a clunking noise while turning the steering wheel at low speed. Went under the car to find that the passenger side inner CV joint has maybe ~2mm of play side-to-side and clunks:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJQEhOubdU4FRiYyZoUlMCjhyfnuiVaC/view?usp=sharing
This is happening on the passenger side only (i.e. the longer CV axle). The axles are original as far as I know.
I've recently done ball joints and I had to tap the axle out of the steering knuckle with a hammer... worried I hit it too hard and messed it up.
Is a new CV axle needed here? Is there some component of the inner joint I should try replacing first? Or anything else?
Thanks

It is possible that the axle is worn out, but there are other potential causes.
Do you hear the clicking when turning in both directions? Normally clicking noises that get worse are from the outer joint. The outer joint is designed for more range of motion, such as following the angle of the wheel in a turn. The inner will only be more strained in a turn, but doesn't articulate as much.
Did the noise only start after you did the ball joints? Did you replace the hole control arm in the process?
I doubt you would damage the axle by knocking it out of the knuckle, you would sooner flare the end or damage the threads. But anything is possible.
Some play is acceptable, but this is either up to experience or a spec, if available.

No clicking when turning at all that I can identify. The noise did start after I did the ball joints, but not immediately: I did around 600mi/1000km with no issues, then I did a longer 500mi/800km drive that included some rough roads and noticed it afterwards. I haven't touched the control arms.
Note that the play & knocking noise shown in the video is only present on one axle, the other one has no play or noise.
